# problem with a kbhit implementation

Tags: c, linux

This is the kbhit implementation that I found, but for some reason it just waits a key to be pressed instead of returning some result other than 0. It doesn't really function as kbhit...

```
int kbhit(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set read_fd;

    tv.tv_sec=0;
    tv.tv_usec=0;
    FD_ZERO(&read_fd);
    FD_SET(0,&read_fd);

    if(select(1, &read_fd, NULL, NULL, &tv) == -1)
        return 0;

    if(FD_ISSET(0,&read_fd))
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain me what the problem is?
I'm using Linux, btw.

I think you might have misunderstood me, and thought that it actully returns non zero value after a key stroke.
my problem is that kbhit always WAITS for a key stroke.

Comment: Why didn't you use the kbhit implementation I sent you the link for in answer to your previous question ?

Answer (score 0):

stdin is probably line-buffered. You'll need to switch it to unbuffered while trying to detect a keypress.

Comment: technically, stdin would be on canonical mode. setvbuf() is for output streams.